# progress bar is not appearing on assigned location

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i want to display three progress bar in one line in but when I run my code first progress bar is not displaying on the page. But second and third is displaying. Can you please tell me what I am doing the mistake.

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="8" Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="15" Padding="5" VerticalOptions="Start"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0,-10">
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="33" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="33" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="34" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!--<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="upload.png"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" />-->
                            <Label x:Name="LableInbound" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Inbound"  TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="-5,-10,0,0" />
                            <Label x:Name="LableOutbound" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Outbound" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="-5,-10,0,0"  />
                            <Label x:Name="LableDelivery" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Delivery" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="-5,-10,0,0" />

                            <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="OrderUploadProgressInbound"  HeightRequest="20" Progress="1" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="0,-10,0,0"   />
                            <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="OrderUploadProgressOutbound"   HeightRequest="20" Progress="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-10,0,0"   />
                            <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="OrderUploadProgressDelivery"  HeightRequest="20" Progress="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"  Margin="0,-10,0,0"   />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this problem is that the property Grid.Column should starts from 0, not 1.
I modity your code to the following and it works well.

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="8" Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="15" Padding="5" VerticalOptions="Start"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0,-10">
                    <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="34*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="OrderUploadProgressInbound" WidthRequest="100"  HeightRequest="20" Progress="1" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="7,0,0,0"   />
                        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="OrderUploadProgressOutbound" WidthRequest="100"  HeightRequest="20" Progress="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0"   />
                        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="OrderUploadProgressDelivery" WidthRequest="100"  HeightRequest="20" Progress="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"  Margin="15,0,0,0"   />
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
```

Comment: i have edited my xml  code as per above. Just i have edit my question xml part. I have edit xaml as per your guidance but this is not showing again. can you please tell me what is the issue in above code

Comment: As I donot have your whole code, I am not quite sure where the problem is. What I did is simplely new a xamarin form project, and edit "MainPage.xaml" file to add a Grid using your code, and modify the Grid.Column value from 1, 2, 3 to 0, 1, 2.  and it works.

Comment: If it is convienent for you, would you give me the complete souce code, so that I can try to help you figure out where the problem is. As I guess now it is concernted with the code elsewhere.

Comment: thanks for your word i have upload xaml page on google drive that you can download from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18isRo_iXT0GDHzjxHJoV_n407TeuhA-7?usp=sharing

Comment: problem with line no 140 to 160